# Multiple Release and Debug Options For Different Clients

Tags: android

I have an android app in use by several clients, when I build the app currently I have 2 options 1. release and 2. debug

Now my problem is some om my clients require certain features others do not, meaning that for the same app some features might be disabled for some clients while other clients would  have extra features.

I would like to know how I can have more than one release option when building my app. eg.

1. ClientARelease
2. ClientBRelease
3. ClientCRelease
4. ClientADebug
5. ClientBDebug
6. ClientCDebug

So if Client A wants all features of the app but client B does not when I select ClientBRelease the features not required by ClientB are not bundled with the apk.

How do I achieve this with android?

Comment: How are these features organised within the project structure? Are those libraries/modules?

Comment: No they are not separate libraries or modules but I have grouped the activities into different packages.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Android Build Types and Build Flavors. Check out [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

> Each build variant represents a different version of your app that you can build. For example, you might want to build one version of your app that's free, with a limited set of content, and another paid version that includes more. You can also build different versions of your app that target different devices, based on API level or other device variations.
>
> Creating product flavors is similar to creating build types: add them
>   to the productFlavors block in your build configuration and include
>   the settings you want.
>
> In some cases, you may want to combine configurations from multiple
>   product flavors. For example, you may want to create different
>   configurations for the "full" and "demo" product flavors that are
>   based on API level. To do this, the Android plugin for Gradle allows
>   you to create multiple groups of product flavors as flavor dimensions.
>   When building your app, Gradle combines a product flavor configuration
>   from each flavor dimension you define, along with a build type
>   configuration, to create the final build variant.

Also for some cases you can use APK splitting/AppBundle.